# Using Kubernetes client-go how to check programatically if Node is "Ready"?

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

It looks like I might need to traverse the `v1.Node->NodeStatus->Conditions[]` slice and sort by transition time and find if the most recent timed condition is `NodeConditionType == "Ready"`. I am wondering if there is a better way or if that approach is flawed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking in the right place, but Conditions may not work exactly the way your question implies they do. Conditions shouldn't be seen as time-based events, but rather current states. To quote the [API conventions documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#typical-status-properties):

> Conditions represent the latest available observations of an object's state.

As such, it isn't necessary to look for the latest Condition, but rather *the* condition for the type of state that you are interested in observing. There should only be one whose `NodeConditionType` is `Ready`, but you will need to check the `.Status` field on `NodeCondition` to confirm if its value is `True`, `False` or `Unknown`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks... this is the conclusion I came to as well before seeing this answer when I woke up.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I enable [`TaintBasedEvictions` and `TaintNodesByCondition`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/#taint-based-evictions) feature gates,  and k8s node-controller will add some taints (e.g. `node.kubernetes.io/not-ready`, `node.kubernetes.io/unreachable`) automatically on node, I only need to watch node, and check taint.